# cPanel Issue The security token is missing from your request

Tags: php, token, cpanel, whm

Yesterday one of the servers at our datacenter which has cPanel/WHM installed had a network card blow out so we had to migrate to a new server.
Since then users are always getting the:

> The security token is missing from your request.

The error which doesn't accrue on WHM the only cPanel. Yet I read online to clear browser cookies but It seems that the issue is server-wide not only myself.

Even when reentering the cPanel password it directs to the cpanel url with a token in, then before anything shows go straight back to the login screen, and does it constantly completely disabling cPanel access.
Does anyone have any ideas on a fix? It has stopped many clients being able to log in.

See the video I have attached too - https://vimeo.com/390572869

Answer (score 0):

NOTE : The below steps will not work on latest cPanel version.

1. Log into WHM using server ‘root’ password
2. Search for “Tweak Settings” in WHM search bar
3. Uncheck “Require security tokens for all interfaces”
4. save “Tweak Settings”

You can do the same from server backend

1. Log into server via SSH as ‘root’ user
2. Edit the file /var/cpanel/cpanel.config using vi editor

vi /var/cpanel/cpanel.config

3. You will see the line “xsrftokens=1”

Change the line xsrftokens=1 to xsrftokens=0

4. Save the file and exit

5 Run the below command on the server to update tweak settings

Command : /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/bin/whostmgr2 –updatetweaksettings

Now Try accessing cPanel/WHM/webmail in the browser and you won’t see any Security token missing errors.